# Set the title of Accordion in Semantic.JS

Tags: jquery, html, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic UI JS for implementing various UI functionalities. Here is the link for the [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion.html#fluid).   I need to set the value of the Title dynamically. Here in the below example "Title 1". Looking for a way to do it using JQuery.

```html
<div class="ui styled accordion">
  <div class="title">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    Title 1
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p class="transition hidden">Content of the title</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wrap the title text in a `span` element so that i could target it and change the text with the jQuery `.text()` method.

```js
$(function() {
  // initialize accordion
  $('.ui.accordion')
    .accordion({
      selector: {
        trigger: '.title'
      }
    })

  // change title on button click
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $('.title span').text('The new title to use')
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.css')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui styled accordion">
  <div class="title">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <span>Title 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p class="transition hidden">Content of the title</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button>Change the title</button>
```

Comment: Great help! The trick adding SPAN element to identify the text :) Thank you Gaby :)